# how to use 士 in a sentence as a word by itself?

Tags: sentence

I am studying Kanji and it helps me to learn vocabulary in context.  I understand 士 is a word by itself, meaning "man (esp. one who is well-respected)​" https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A3%AB

In websites I looked at for sentences, I only found ones where this kanji was part of another word (which I'm also interested in learning, but that's not my question)

- [tatoeba search](https://tatoeba.org/en/sentences/search?from=jpn&has_audio=&native=&orphans=no&query=%E5%A3%AB&sort_reverse=&tags=&to=eng&trans_filter=limit&trans_has_audio=&trans_link=direct&trans_orphan=no&trans_to=eng&trans_unapproved=no&trans_user=&unapproved=no&user=&page=2&sort=words)
- [jisho search](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%A3%AB%20%23sentences)

If I try to make up English sentences and look for translations, I get sentences with [男](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%94%B7), which makes sense to me.

Would someone be able to provide some example sentences with 士 that are what someone would actually say or write in Japan?  or if it is old-fashioned and not used much, maybe a proverb or quote would be interesting to learn.

Comment: I have never seen 士 on its own except as a rare alternative spelling of 侍{さむらい}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the only pattern where 士{し} appears by itself is Xの士 with some [kango](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E) X. But X is rather restricted, and the pattern is hardly productive.

A search with の士 on [Shonagon](https://shonagon.ninjal.ac.jp/) includes the following:

- [憂国の士](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%86%82%E5%9B%BD%E3%81%AE%E5%A3%AB) Typically someone like Yukio Mishima.
- [具眼の士](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%85%B7%E7%9C%BC%E3%81%AE%E5%A3%AB) A man of insight. (contains -の士 expressions as synonyms)
- [同好の士](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%90%8C%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%AE%E5%A3%AB) people with the same hobby. E.g. fans of the same idol can call each other 同好の士.
- 清廉潔白の士 A man of integrity.
- 智謀の士 A man of tactics.
- 武勇の士 A man of courage.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "pattern is hardly productive."  Are you referring to not many options with that pattern or just that you wouldn't say it often because of how gendered it is (if that's even a thing in Japan, like it is where I live/work in US)?  (For my purpose, of helping me memorize the Kanji, it seems like it would be quite productive!)

Comment: @Ultrasaurus By 'hardly productive', I mean the set of words that can work as X in the pattern is almost fixed and not expanding in the current usage. In other words, when you want to use Aの士 for a particular word A and google search does not give examples of Aの士, it is unlikely to be usable.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)